# Persistent Command Line Display

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line

I am writing a little Sudoku solving app in Ruby that just outputs to the terminal. For example:

```
 ruboku $ ruby grid.rb
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 8 | 5 |   | 3 | 1 | 7 | 6 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5 |   | 4 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Is there a way to keep this as a persistent display such that when there is new information to show it doesn't print a new line, but updates the grid that is already displaying?

I've seen some tools such as ngrok who do this.

Thanks for your time,

Tom

Comment: You mean a library like `ncourses`, which allows you to control the display to the level of printing in a certain (row,column) position?

Comment: Thanks @ed-de-almeida, do you mean instead of 'ngrok' or that I should look at ncourses? If the former, I just meant that when you use the tool it has a persistent display. Is this the library you are referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses?

Comment: Yes its called `ncurses` (or the preceding `curses`).

Comment: Yes, I thought about a more sophisitcated approach, printing to a permanent screen with ncourses. But you may surely consider other options. The most easy, of course, is clearing the screen and printing the board all over again, for each new position filled. I did this once in a go-moku game I was programming and it worked well.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks guys. I'm checking out the [ncurses ruby gem](https://github.com/eclubb/ncurses-ruby) and also [vedeu](https://github.com/gavinlaking/vedeu) which looks good! Interesting suggestion on clearing the screen @eddealmeida, much simpler! I will look at that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs, erasing the screen and creating the grid again could be good enough :

```
def show_grid
  line = '+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+'
  puts line
  9.times do
    row = (1..9).map { rand(9) + 1 }
    puts '| ' + row.join(' | ') + ' |'
    puts line
  end
end

def clear_screen
  system('clear') || system('cls')
end

loop do
  clear_screen
  show_grid
  sleep 1
end
```

It outputs

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 9 | 8 | 6 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 8 | 1 | 7 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 8 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 3 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 7 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 9 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 9 | 1 | 9 | 3 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 8 | 5 | 4 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 8 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 3 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

then

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 6 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 8 | 7 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 4 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 6 | 7 | 1 | 9 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 6 | 7 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 7 | 6 | 7 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 8 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 7 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 9 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 9 | 6 | 3 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

then...

It should work on Windows/Linux/MacOs.

For anything more complex, you'll need an ncurses gem.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! You've also just suggested a much more efficient way of printing the lines than I had been doing so doubly useful!

Answer (score 1):

So the question is marked as answered I thought I would write up the advice given to me in the comments.

It looks like the [ncurses ruby gem](https://github.com/eclubb/ncurses-ruby) and [vedeu](https://github.com/gavinlaking/vedeu) offer the functionality that I need. Another alternative would be to clear the scren and reprint the output.